# Java get the object that is not null

Tags: java, null

I have an array with 4 objects, and only one of them is not `null`. I want to call a method, giving that variable as a param.

```
Block[] b = getIntersectingBlocks(e); // I get 4 Block variables, and only one of them is not null
// ...
Listener.myMethod(notNullBlock); // notNullBlock should be the block out of the array, that is not null
```

What is the fastest way of doing that, and avoiding `if - else` statements like this:

```
if (b[0] != null) {
    Listener.myMethod(b[0]);
} else if (b[2] != null) {
    Listener.myMethod(b[1]);
}
// ...
```

Comment: How do you check _if_ something is not `null`? Also, an object cannot be `null`. An array variable (an array element) can reference `null`.

Comment: Sorry -_- I meant variable xD

Comment: why not just use a for/in loop? then you would only need one if

Comment: Is there any particular reason the code is structured to return an empty array save for a single element?

Comment: why not put the whole null check thing inside one big if() with an OR condition

Comment: fastest null check for an element in array of size 4??? why not just use for/if combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understand your question, you could do it with a massive nested ternary (please don't do this in real code),

```
final Block notNullBlock = (b == null || b.length != 4) ? null :
    b[0] != null ? b[0] : b[1] != null ? b[1] : b[2] != null ? b[2] :
    b[3];
```

You could also use a for-each loop (but it requires an `if`) -

```
Block notNullBlock = null;
for (Block block : b) {
  if (block != null) {
    notNullBlock = block;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I was almost going there too, but there are still tests in there, and I don't think it answers the question. I believe he's looking for a general solution that works for an arbitrary length array.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't use multiple `if` and will work for an arbitrary length array:

```
for (Block block : b)
    if (block != null)
        Listener.myMethod(block);
```

If more than one `Block` can be non-null, add a `break` to prevent the listener being called more than once:

```
for (Block block : b) {
    if (block != null) {
        Listener.myMethod(block);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use for each loop

```
for(Block bl:bArray){
   if(bl !=null)
    Listener.myMethod(b1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have an array of Block as below:
    Block[] blocksArray = {null, null, new Block(), null};

Pass above array to this method:

```
    private Block provideBlock(Block[] blocksArray)   { 
        for(Block block : blocksArray) {
            block instanceof Block? return block : continue;
        }
    }
```

Then use returned not null block in your code as:

```
Block block = provideBlock(blocksArray);
Listener.myMethod(block);
```